# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. whrer i shold add the web.cofig file and how exiqute it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

Where should  add the web.cofig file and how exiqute it and i do too many thigs like create an file name webpack.js and all but i am in a confusion that where i should have to place the file in my client side code just about the package.json file or in my backend code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljtq6.png)

i am try to use the webpack 5 but i don't know that how to solve the auto pollyfill problem i want an step by step guidne for this please help  this is my hole error BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need
this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

webpack compiled with 57 errors and 14 warnings     how do i resolve it and where i have to place the webpack.config.js file in my code i already include my file project file structure and yes this  i an react js project

Comment: is this a react project. then i would say don't try to use node-js modules on client.

Comment: as indeed webpack removed nodejs polifils but they also removed due to security reasons.

Comment: still can you explain your problem a little more.

Comment: i want to know how solve this error .

Comment: what are you using "path" module for?